# how to compile from src directory to bin directory?

Tags: compilation, directory, ocaml

I have a src directory that contains main.ml and compose.ml files, and i need to compile from that directory and store the binary result in bin directory.

How can i make it?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that `main.ml` is the main program and `compose.ml` a module it uses. Then the compilation process will produce files `compose.cmo` (or `compose.cmx`), `compose.cmi`, and the final binary.
It is not quite clear, where you want the intermediate files (`compose.cmo` and `compose.cmi`) to go.

If you are fine with them being in `src`, you can use the `-o` command line option in the final compilation step.

If you want to keep the source directory clean but are fine with extra stuff going to `bin`, I suggest symlinking your source files to `bin` and compile there.

If you want to keep both `src` and `bin` clean, you can use a third directory like `build`, where you symlink the sources, compile, and copy the final binary to `bin`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is probably to use ocamlbuild:

```
ocamlbuild -I src -no-links main.native
ln -f _build/src/main.native bin/main
```

This will leave the temporary files in the `_build` directory, which you can later remove with `ocamlbuild -clean` or `rm -r _build`.

Use `main.byte` instead of `main.native` instead if you want to build the bytecode version.